# The infinite product of matrices whose spectral radius are uniformly less than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ergodic-theory, random-matrices

Consider a set of $n\times n$ irreducible and aperiodic Markov matrices $\{M_n\}$, we assume each row sum up to be 1 and each entry is nonnegative. 
 Assume there exists a uniform bound $a$ for the spectrum gap, i.e,

$$ \|\lambda_2(M)\|<1-a $$

If each row of $M$ subtract the last row and we only take the first n-1 rows and n-1 columns, it generates a new matrix $J$,

$$  J=\begin{pmatrix}
  M_{1,1}-M_{n,1} & M_{1,2}-M_{n,2} & \cdots & M_{1,n-1}-M_{n,n-1} \\
  M_{2,1}-M_{n,1} & M_{2,2}-M_{n,2} & \cdots & M_{2,n-1}-M_{n,n-1} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  M_{n-1,1}-M_{n,1} & M_{n-1,2}-M_{n,2} & \cdots & M_{n-1,n-1}-M_{n,n-1} 
 \end{pmatrix} $$
Then we have a set of matrices $\{J_n\}$, one in fact can show the eigenvalues of $J$ is the same as all eigenvalues of the corresponding $M$ that are within unit circle. So the spectrum radius of $J$ is uniformly less than 1.

I would like to show the infinite product of J from the set goes to zero, i.e,
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Pi_{i=1}^n J_i=0, \ \ \text{for}\ J_i\in \{J_n\}  $$

The numerical simulation shows it is true. If I can find a matrix norm such that the norm of all $J$ matrix is strictly less than 1, it is also proved.

Comment: To show the eigenvalues of $J$ is the same as all eigenvalues of $M$ that are within the unit disk, one can find the characteristic polynomial of J is $det(M-\lambda I)=(1-\lambda)det(J-\lambda I)$